# Springboot override x-frame-options from external library (currently adding multiple)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, x-frame-options

I am having an issue in my spring app, basically I have overridden the configure method for WebSecurity in angular to use SAMEORIGIN as the X-FRAME-OPTION which works and applies the header.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(95)
public class CCWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN));
    }

}
```

However I include a usersecurity library which also overrides the configure method, the method for this can be seen below:

[image: Code Screenshot]

Am I correct in saying it is the 'csrf().disable()' that is responsible for the X-FRAME-OPTIONS - DENY being applied?

Ideally I wanted to avoid changing the usersecurity library as there are many other of my spring apps relying on this.

Comment: I believe there is no relationship between `csrf().disable()` and `X-FRAME-OPTIONS`.

Comment: CSFR is something else and has nothing to do with `x-frame-options`.

Comment: Thanks! You guys any idea which of the security calls in the screenshot may be responsible for the DENY then?

Comment: Adding `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` in **filter** or **interceptor** could be solution I guess.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna this would still have the same issue of X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY already being applied though wouldn't it? Unless I can remove them on interception.

Comment: are you aware of some way of removing x-frame-options in spring security? so when my code block runs in the question is there anyway you are aware of to remove headers?

Comment: If you remove `x-frame-options` then malicious iframe can be injected to your application for taking input and bypass them.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I am aware of that, however I want to set it to same-origin, but if there is a way to remove individual headers then I can just remove the deny one then add the same-origin X-FRAME-OPTION.

Comment: You can remove for a specific page from filter. If found matching url then remove the header compromising with security flows.

Comment: Why do you think, your problem has someting to do with the second configuration? I would say, that you add the second header in your own configuration. To switch frame option you have to use: `http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can allow multiple URLs as follows, But I don't know weather this is the proper way or not. but it works properly.**

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
    .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .headers().defaultsDisabled()
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .headers()
            .cacheControl()
            .and()
            .contentTypeOptions()
            .and()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable()
            .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().disable()
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-FRAME-OPTIONS",
                    "ALLOW-FROM example1.com",
                    "ALLOW-FROM example2.com",
                    "ALLOW-FROM example3.com",
                    "ALLOW-FROM example4.com",
                    "ALLOW-FROM example5.com"));
```

}